# How do I test if Point is in Polygon/Multipolygon with geopandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, polygon, point, geopandas

I have the Polygon data from the  States from the USA from the website 
[arcgis](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f7f805eb65eb4ab787a0a3e1116ca7e5)
 and I also have an excel file with coordinates of citys. I have converted the coordinates to geometry data (Points).
Now I want to test if the Points are in the USA.
Both are dtype: geometry. I thought with this I can easily compare, but when I use my code I get for every Point the answer false. Even if there are Points that are in the USA.

The code is:

```
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

df1 = pd.read_excel('PATH')
gdf = gp.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry= gp.points_from_xy(df1.longitude, df1.latitude))

US = gp.read_file('PATH')

print(gdf['geometry'].contains(US['geometry']))
```

Does anybody know what I do wrong?

Comment: are your datasets in the same coordinate system?

Comment: rather than rely on datasets that no one else can ride, mock up up a couple of points and rectangles in cartesian space and work from that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`contains` in GeoPandas currently work on a pairwise basis 1-to-1, not 1-to-many. For this purpose, use `sjoin`.

```
points_within = gp.sjoin(gdf, US, predicate='within')
```

That will return only those points within the `US`. Alternatively, you can filter polygons which contain points.

```
polygons_contains = gp.sjoin(US, gdf, predicate='contains')
```